# How to modify three columns to only one of them having 0 the rest a 1?

Tags: linux, sed, awk, text-editing

Let's say I have a messed up data table like so:

```
Name     IsBuyer IsBidder IsAdmin
person1  1       1        0
person2  1       0        1
person3  1       1        1
.
.
```

The three columns IsBuyer, IsBidder, IsAdmin can be true or false. But only one of the columns can be true.

How would one write a script using sed, awk or other UNIX/Linux based tool to modify the table like that?

Comment: How do you know which column should be set to 1?

Comment: Well, that doesn't really matter. The important part is that only one column can be true. In my application, a user can only be either a buyer, a bidder or and admin.

Comment: Can you please add a follow-up about whether you were able to solve this issue and how or provide more info if you are still stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this file named e.g. `users.txt` and you just want to fix it so your application will start and allow you to examine and work out the situation; you could just set `IsBuyer` to `1` and `IsBidder` and `IsAdmin` to `0`.

Choose your flavour between `awk` and `perl`:

`awk 'NR==1; /person/ && $2+$3+$4>1 {print $1 "  1       0        0"}' users.txt`

`perl -lape 'if (/person/ && $F[1]+$F[2]+$F[3]>1) {$_="$F[0]  1       0        0"}' users.txt`

A slightly more sophisticated approach would be to only set `IsBuyer` to `1` if it was found to be `1` i.e. flip values to `0` but never flip values to `1`. Of course, I have no idea whether this would make sense in your situation, as it depends on what kind of data corruption has happened.